# Hat earned before date in Winterbash

Tags: bug, winter-bash

It's not yet 18th December 2015 but I have earned the `A New Hope` hat on Stack Overflow which says:

> ask, answer, or vote on December 18th

Proof:

[image]

Possible Bug?

Comment: I don't think you should delete it, but instead click the "This helped me" (or however it displays exactly) button to confirm it's a duplicate.